nifi: jvm settings from bootstrap.conf vs from outside
For nifi, we have jvm options in bootstrap.conf:
java.arg.2=-Xms512m
java.arg.3=-Xmx512m

Then we also have env variables that can be set from outside:
NIFI_JVM_HEAP_INIT
NIFI_JVM_HEAP_MAX

What's the connection between these 2 sets of properties?
